# Is there a way to make a list about counting occurence of different variables for different elements in the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, counter

```
sumlist = [
    ['a01', '01-24-2017', 's1'],
    ['a03', '01-24-2017', 's2'],
    ['a03', '09-24-2017', 's1'],
    ['a03', '10-23-2017', 's1'],
    ['a04', '11-01-2017', 's1'],
    ['a04', '11-02-2017', 's2'],
    ['a04', '11-03-2017', 's1'],
    ['a04', '01-01-2017', 's1']]
```

This is the list of lists I am working on currently, and the question is to count the occurrence of s1 and s2 for each element (a01, a03, a04). The only way I know is to use count(), but it only works for a single element.

After I used Counter and default (Thanks for @JPP 's help!):

`d = defaultdict(Counter)
        for animal, date, station in sumlist:
            d[animal][station] += 1`

I get:

`defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>, 
{'a04': Counter({'s2': 5, 's1': 5}), 
'a01': Counter({'s1': 2, 's2': 1}), 
'a03': Counter({'s1': 6, 's2': 4})}`

There are the numbers of occurrence, but Is there a way to make two dictionary like:

`{a01: number of occurrences of S1, a04: the number of occureneces of S1, a03: number of occurrences of S1}` and same for S2?

Thank you very much !

Comment: If you only have `{a01: number of occurrence}`, how do you know if number of occurrence refers to s1 or to s2 ? Do you mean to sum the number of occurrences?

Comment: oh, i want to make two dictionaries, one for s1 and another one for s2

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is a `defaultdict` of `Counter` objects:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

d = defaultdict(Counter)

for key, _, val in sumlist:
    d[key][val] += 1

print(d)

defaultdict(collections.Counter,
            {'a01': Counter({'s1': 1}),
             'a03': Counter({'s1': 2, 's2': 1}),
             'a04': Counter({'s1': 3, 's2': 1})})
```

---

Invert `key` and `val` if you wish your value to be the key:

```
d = defaultdict(Counter)

for key, _, val in sumlist:
    d[val][key] += 1

print(d)

defaultdict(collections.Counter,
            {'s1': Counter({'a01': 1, 'a03': 2, 'a04': 3}),
             's2': Counter({'a03': 1, 'a04': 1})})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
{a:Counter(c[2] for c in l if c[0]==a) for a in set(map(itemgetter(0),l))}
```

That is,

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> set(map(itemgetter(0),l)) #get the zeroth element to get the keys
set(['a03', 'a01', 'a04'])
>>> {a:0 for a in set(map(itemgetter(0),l))} #dict comprehension
{'a03': 0, 'a01': 0, 'a04': 0}
>>> {a:[c[2] for c in l if c[0]==a] for a in set(map(itemgetter(0),l))} #if the key matches then get the 2nd index
{'a03': ['s2', 's1', 's1'], 'a01': ['s1'], 'a04': ['s1', 's2', 's1', 's1']}
>>> {a:Counter(c[2] for c in l if c[0]==a) for a in set(map(itemgetter(0),l))}
{'a03': Counter({'s1': 2, 's2': 1}), 'a01': Counter({'s1': 1}), 'a04': Counter({'s1': 3, 's2': 1})}
```